# How do I specify color for output file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to change the color of certain lines when creating a file in python. For example if I want all lines with A to be green and the rest default.

```
logfile = open("dirpath/file",'w')
logfile.write("A\n")
logfile.write("B\n")
logfile.close()
```

Its on Linux by the way

Comment: unless I am mistaken (I'm only a poor Windows guy), lines in a text file don't have colour, even in python on Linux. Lines on the console output do, is that what you are after?

Answer (score 4):

Files don't have color

You could (possibly) inject control characters that switch the console default color as the file is printed on the shell. But that would only work with a particular setup (and be a really bad idea)

If you want text to have a color you need to write files in a format that contains colors, such as html and display it in an app that understands the format

Answer (score 1):

The color of text is dependent on the program displaying the text. Standard ASCII text has no color, so you need to specify where these files will be viewed. For example, are you talking about webpages?

Answer (score 0):

Use `multitail` with a custom filter to view the file (From the terminal). If not, programs such as `Log File Viewer` (Gnome) can also apply filters. This will allow you to colour the file depending on whatever criteria you need.